# SVG that won't load in illustrator - saying "This SVG is invalid. Validate it before opening."

Tags: svg, inkscape

Here's the code - let me know if there's anything you see missing or unneeded. The file displays just fine in chrome :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<svg style="fill: rgb(62, 156, 205); width:15%; float:left; margin-right:5%;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 152.69 149.72"><path d="M151.37 81.59c-.88.15-1.76.3-2.55.27-.88-.03-1.61-.8-2.39-1.02-.83-.23-1.69-.21-2.43-.62-.74-.41-1.31-1.04-1.97-1.6-.64-.54-1.12-1.23-1.7-1.87-.57-.62-1.4-1.02-1.92-1.71-.53-.7-1.08-1.36-1.65-1.96-.6-.64-1.32-1.1-1.96-1.63-.67-.56-1.38-.97-2.08-1.42-.72-.46-1.35-1.05-2.12-1.39-.77-.35-1.47-.94-2.29-1.18-.8-.23-1.73.07-2.57-.05-.82-.13-1.63-.1-2.49-.13-.82-.03-1.65-.31-2.51-.26-.82.06-1.62.37-2.47.5-1.13.17-2.08.05-2.41-.31-.35-.38-.38-1.39.03-2.5.29-.8.73-1.55 1.16-2.17.47-.68 1.3-.99 1.91-1.47.61-.49 1.26-.87 1.99-1.19.7-.31 1.38-.76 2.16-.94.75-.17 1.55-.17 2.35-.25.91-.09 1.77-.58 2.67-.68.9-.09 1.84.13 2.74-.01.9-.14 1.82-.15 2.71-.37.79-.2 1.57-.42 2.28-.7.76-.3 1.24-1.07 1.91-1.46.7-.4 1.5-.57 2.1-1.07.61-.51 1.35-.91 1.87-1.51.51-.6.56-1.56.98-2.25.41-.67 1.07-1.19 1.4-1.94.32-.71.78-1.41 1.03-2.19.31-.99.68-2.66-.42-3.39-.94-.62-2.17.46-2.97.97-.76.48-1.74.35-2.51.64-.82.3-1.55.59-2.39.7-.85.11-1.66.47-2.53.41-.84-.06-1.63-.52-2.48-.71-.82-.19-1.6-.48-2.43-.77-.79-.28-1.63-.4-2.42-.66s-1.59-.58-2.39-.79c-.81-.21-1.7.05-2.53-.07-.82-.12-1.62-.39-2.46-.38-.79.01-1.58-.06-2.33.03-.78.1-1.5.45-2.23.66-.75.21-1.37.66-2.06 1-.69.34-1.35.64-1.97 1.13-.59.46-1.23.88-1.76 1.49-.64.75-1.03 2.43-2.12 2.01-.63-.24-1.05-.81-1.18-1.47-.12-.6.36-1.31.36-1.91 0-.83-.49-1.73-.26-2.49.23-.75.63-1.54 1.09-2.24.47-.71 1.19-1.23 1.78-1.8.6-.57 1.5-.73 2.18-1.22.67-.48 1.1-1.33 1.8-1.77.67-.42 1.16-1.04 1.76-1.53.61-.5 1.36-.8 1.91-1.36.55-.57 1.02-1.2 1.5-1.82.49-.63.83-1.33 1.24-2 .41-.68 1.11-1.19 1.44-1.91.33-.73.82-1.42 1.06-2.17.24-.77-.06-1.69.08-2.46.14-.8.3-1.56.32-2.35.02-.81-.08-1.58-.19-2.37-.11-.8-.22-1.57-.48-2.33-.27-.81-.33-2.11-1.34-2.19-.98-.07-1.23 1.08-1.54 1.71-.37.75-.68 1.45-1.11 2.1-.46.69-.44 1.76-.98 2.33-.56.59-1.6.59-2.26 1.04-.65.44-1.17 1.12-1.93 1.41-.72.28-1.56.08-2.38.21-.75.13-1.48.88-2.32.88-.68 0-1.35-.08-2.03-.03-.68.05-1.34.3-2.02.35-.79.07-1.61-.28-2.34-.11-.77.17-1.62.15-2.32.43-.73.29-1.12 1.26-1.78 1.66-.67.4-1.5.53-2.08 1.04-.58.51-.84 1.31-1.32 1.93-.47.61-1.48.88-1.85 1.58-.36.68-.65 1.48-.9 2.24-.24.73-.02 1.62-.15 2.42-.13.79.06 1.88-1.13 2-.95.1-1.69-.57-2.23-1.27-.57-.74-.63-1.73-.98-2.5-.39-.83-.64-1.6-.8-2.45-.17-.87-.56-1.71-.53-2.6.04-.87.58-1.66.78-2.53.19-.84.41-1.65.72-2.49.27-.74.3-1.57.56-2.31.26-.74.1-1.62.31-2.37.21-.76.97-1.38 1.11-2.15.14-.77-.31-1.62-.29-2.41.03-.79.33-1.56.28-2.32-.06-.79.09-1.62-.07-2.37-.17-.77-.64-1.47-.92-2.19s-.57-1.46-.98-2.13C85.77 3 83.7-.34 81.61.03c-.1.56.14.93.2 1.44.14 1.17-.2 2.28-.45 3.4-.19.87.1 1.89-.26 2.67-.35.79-1.39 1.18-1.87 1.91-.47.71-.52 1.76-1.08 2.43-.55.65-1.34 1.1-1.94 1.72-.59.62-.93 1.51-1.55 2.12-.48.47-1.1.79-1.59 1.24-.6.55-1.28.95-1.79 1.5-.56.59-1.11 1.15-1.56 1.75-.49.65-1.03 1.25-1.4 1.9-.4.71-.67 1.47-.92 2.19-.27.76 0 1.61-.11 2.38-.11.78-.33 1.5-.28 2.31.05.77 0 1.57.21 2.36.19.74.2 1.6.52 2.36.31.73 1.71 1.77.7 2.48-.76.53-1.97-.11-2.75-.51-.76-.39-1.65-.59-2.27-1.09-.66-.53-.85-1.54-1.34-2.18-.49-.66-.8-1.36-1.12-2.14-.3-.74-.51-1.48-.65-2.33-.12-.73-.78-1.39-.89-2.12-.11-.74.13-1.52.02-2.26-.11-.74-.19-1.48-.33-2.21s-.02-1.54-.21-2.26c-.22-.83-.58-1.62-.87-2.39-.3-.8-1.07-1.37-1.45-2.09-.39-.75-.71-1.51-1.19-2.18-.49-.68-.7-1.62-1.28-2.22-.57-.59-1.26-1.14-1.93-1.65-.65-.49-1.6-.55-2.33-.95-.7-.39-1.39-.83-2.18-1.15-.74-.29-1.49-.66-2.3-.88-.55-.15-1.23-.53-1.74-.06-.44.41-.3 1.12-.04 1.53.44.69 1.18 1.15 1.47 1.85.31.75.57 1.51.72 2.26.15.77-.06 1.58-.05 2.36.01.77.44 1.6.33 2.39-.11.76-.6 1.47-.8 2.23-.19.74-.61 1.41-.87 2.16-.28.79-.42 1.62-.64 2.41-.22.81-.37 1.63-.51 2.43-.14.82.12 1.68.07 2.5-.05.83-.29 1.63-.24 2.46.05.82.24 1.62.4 2.44.16.8.29 1.61.57 2.4.27.76.88 1.36 1.27 2.12.37.71.24 1.77.73 2.47.33.48 1.21.71 1.53 1.24.33.55.42 1.31.04 1.95-.39.66-1.14.6-1.84.68-.66.08-1.36.02-2.02.03-.75.01-1.5.27-2.2.07-.7-.2-1.38-.56-2.04-.9-.68-.36-1.38-.69-1.97-1.14-.61-.46-1-1.17-1.52-1.71-.53-.54-1.35-.84-1.82-1.43-.46-.6-.4-1.59-.82-2.23-.47-.7-1.38-1.03-1.92-1.64-.55-.63-.73-1.65-1.35-2.18-.63-.54-1.73-.41-2.41-.85-.7-.44-1.09-1.47-1.83-1.79-.75-.33-1.55-.68-2.34-.89-.79-.21-1.68-.02-2.49-.1-.8-.08-1.63-.18-2.44-.13-.8.05-1.67-.02-2.46.16-.66.15-2.11.41-2.32 1.19-.24.9.94 1.81 1.65 2.24.74.46 1.6.63 2.2 1.16.65.57.97 1.37 1.48 2.02.52.67 1.37 1.09 1.76 1.83.39.74.43 1.65.7 2.45.27.79.89 1.5 1.07 2.33.17.81.24 1.68.34 2.53.08.72-.11 1.47.07 2.17.18.69.13 1.49.41 2.17.31.75 1.04 1.29 1.43 1.95.41.69.75 1.42 1.23 2.02.5.61 1.25.96 1.83 1.49.57.53 1.23.9 1.87 1.35.63.45 1.24.89 1.93 1.27.67.37 1.33.75 2.05 1.06.7.31 1.46.43 2.21.69 1.14.4 1.96 1.07 2.12 1.59.17.58-.51 1.37-1.27 2.23-.5.56-.87 1.36-1.49 1.75-.62.39-1.57.09-2.29.29-.69.2-1.35.46-2.1.48-.71.02-1.47.23-2.22.09-.7-.14-1.31-.69-2.02-.98-.7-.28-1.36-.63-2.05-.93-.69-.3-1.55-.18-2.24-.48-.93-.39-1.91-.58-2.83-1.03-.36-.18-.74-.34-1.13-.39-.83-.11-1.54-.81-2.38-.94-.73-.11-1.5-.24-2.26-.25-.84-.01-1.64.41-2.43.49-.83.08-1.73-.28-2.51-.1-.81.19-1.47.84-2.23 1.14-.76.31-1.72.24-2.43.67-.69.42-.92 1.52-1.55 2.07-.61.52-1.5.75-2.06 1.39-.55.63-.91 1.33-.35 2.14.54.78 1.07.03 1.77-.17.78-.22 1.62-.12 2.37-.18.8-.06 1.53.34 2.28.48.76.14 1.5.18 2.21.54.67.34 1.58.44 2.2 1 .5.46 1.03.93 1.5 1.43.47.5.51 1.39.94 1.92.44.53 1.06.9 1.46 1.45.52.71 1.06 1.36 1.61 1.97.59.65 1 1.48 1.63 2.01.66.56 1.34 1.15 2.05 1.58.73.44 1.66.49 2.44.79.78.3 1.51.92 2.34 1.08.8.15 1.69.06 2.55.08.81.02 1.65-.13 2.51-.22.8-.08 1.54-.66 2.39-.83.96-.2 2.79-1.09 3.55.02.4.59.25 1.7.06 2.3-.19.58-.7 1.17-1.04 1.67-.49.73-1.34 1.15-2.02 1.69-.66.52-1.28 1.22-2.08 1.59-.69.31-1.45.48-2.17.71-.72.23-1.42.6-2.16.76-.74.15-1.52.11-2.27.21-.74.1-1.52-.05-2.27.01-.91.07-1.79.32-2.68.48-.9.15-1.87-.01-2.74.24-.87.25-1.49 1.2-2.33 1.56-.76.32-1.66.31-2.33.77-.68.46-1.11 1.22-1.68 1.8-.59.59-1.42.94-1.89 1.62-.53.67-.55 1.61-.87 2.37-.33.77-.52 1.52-.68 2.33-.16.82-.52 1.59-.49 2.42.02.54-.34 1.61.33 1.85.35.12 1.31-.19 1.62-.47.6-.54.96-1.28 1.57-1.67.67-.43 1.31-.88 1.98-1.14.72-.28 1.49-.44 2.23-.54.75-.1 1.53-.23 2.3-.17.74.06 1.53.16 2.29.36.71.19 1.25 1 1.98 1.3.68.28 1.41.46 2.11.83.7.37 1.49.52 2.18.82.72.31 1.42.64 2.14.88.75.24 1.48.51 2.22.66.76.15 1.53.34 2.29.39.77.05 1.56.04 2.32-.04.76-.08 1.48-.42 2.23-.62.72-.2 1.5-.32 2.21-.65.67-.31 1.26-.84 1.92-1.28.62-.41 1.23-.86 1.83-1.39.73-.64 1.23-1.61 2.52-.91 1.12.61 1.84 1.53 1.91 2.71.06.99-.68 1.85-.91 2.76-.23.89-.28 1.82-.89 2.62-.47.62-.94 1.22-1.47 1.77-.54.55-1.22.91-1.81 1.41-.58.49-1.16.97-1.78 1.42-.69.5-1.11 1.33-1.74 1.86-.65.55-1.48.87-2.06 1.46-.59.61-.82 1.52-1.33 2.18-.52.67-1.59.95-2 1.68-.42.73-.82 1.54-1.13 2.34-.3.78-.41 1.68-.59 2.54-.17.81.28 1.73.22 2.61-.05.74-.46 1.45-.41 2.18.05.74.13 1.49.35 2.2.21.69.61 1.32 1.02 1.97.31.49.65 1.38 1.3 1.38.94 0 .94-1.16 1.1-1.76.19-.69.21-1.43.4-2.11.19-.67.79-1.04 1.29-1.62.49-.56.53-1.57 1.07-2.02.56-.46 1.19-.95 1.82-1.28.63-.33 1.37-.62 2.07-.82.67-.19 1.47 0 2.22-.06.71-.06 1.46.24 2.17.16.71-.08 1.37-.52 2.08-.64.71-.11 1.47.04 2.16-.12.86-.2 1.66-.61 2.43-.91.82-.32 1.51-.87 2.21-1.31.74-.46 1.62-.73 2.24-1.31.62-.59.71-1.65 1.21-2.36.49-.69.95-1.34 1.33-2.15.35-.76.74-1.5.99-2.36.43-1.48 1.09-2.04 1.7-2.11.58-.07 1.43.22 2.4 1.37.59.7 1.11 1.42 1.46 2.14.39.8.22 1.74.35 2.56.14.84.61 1.69.51 2.53-.1.82-.7 1.55-.98 2.37-.26.78-.55 1.55-.95 2.32-.34.67-.31 1.5-.57 2.18-.27.69-.92 1.24-1.12 1.95-.2.71-.6 1.4-.74 2.13s.09 1.54.01 2.28c-.08.73-.36 1.47-.39 2.22-.04.89.65 1.7.79 2.5.14.86-.11 1.79.22 2.56.33.78.95 1.41 1.45 2.11.48.68.82 1.51 1.44 2.12.58.58 1.16 1.26 1.85 1.78.53.4 1.46 1.08 2.19.71.76-.38.46-1.55.33-2.17-.15-.74.02-1.41.05-2.1.03-.73-.37-1.52-.16-2.2.21-.68.96-1.1 1.32-1.73.35-.61.33-1.48.79-2.05.58-.72 1.53-1.1 2.15-1.78.61-.68 1.02-1.56 1.69-2.2.66-.62 1.35-1.23 2.09-1.79.69-.53 1.61-.78 2.17-1.36.59-.62.76-1.61 1.21-2.29.47-.71.93-1.4 1.26-2.17.34-.77.57-1.58.78-2.4.2-.81.33-1.64.43-2.49.09-.83.55-1.67.55-2.53 0-.84-.39-1.69-.47-2.55-.14-1.46-.12-2.38.36-2.79.47-.4 1.31-.11 2.71.31.96.28 2.06.19 2.78.7.78.56 1.36 1.46 1.86 2.27.47.77 1.03 1.67 1.25 2.65.18.82.29 1.67.44 2.49.15.83.02 1.7.17 2.53.15.83.02 1.71.19 2.53.17.82.33 1.66.55 2.47.23.84 1.06 1.43 1.39 2.18.35.79.58 1.57 1.04 2.26.46.71.84 1.47 1.4 2.08.56.61 1.21 1.14 1.87 1.67.64.52 1.12 1.34 1.84 1.78.7.43 1.72.27 2.48.63.74.35 1.4.89 2.19 1.19.87.33 2.27.95 2.95.16.73-.86-.68-1.66-1.17-2.28-.5-.64-.65-1.44-.97-2.1-.35-.72-.62-1.39-.78-2.12-.17-.76-.6-1.49-.58-2.26.02-.75.05-1.57.22-2.34.16-.73.3-1.53.57-2.27.27-.71 1.08-1.2 1.33-1.91s.48-1.45.68-2.17c.21-.73.39-1.48.53-2.23.14-.74.06-1.53.1-2.29.05-.86.16-1.71.07-2.52-.09-.85-.41-1.65-.62-2.45-.22-.81-.8-1.46-1.13-2.23-.32-.77-.24-1.73-.65-2.47-.4-.72-1.11-1.26-1.58-1.96-.46-.69-1.09-1.24-1.6-1.91-1.21-1.58-.49-2.52 1.12-2.94.9-.24 1.83.05 2.66.05.91 0 1.72.11 2.54.38.83.26 1.82.26 2.57.78.7.48.96 1.55 1.59 2.24.57.62 1.67.78 2.19 1.44.52.66.76 1.56 1.27 2.23.51.67 1.19 1.2 1.73 1.85.55.68 1.08 1.32 1.71 1.91.63.6 1.01 1.52 1.71 2.02.71.5 1.68.55 2.44.94.77.4 1.57.6 2.37.88.81.28 1.49 1.13 2.32 1.29.85.16 1.74.29 2.59.31.86.02 1.75-.16 2.58-.29.84-.13 1.51-.9 2.31-1.2.7-.26 1.67-.04 1.61-.99-.04-.8-.8-.99-1.41-1.22-.75-.3-1.41-.64-2.02-1.07-.64-.45-1.15-1.06-1.59-1.71-.47-.68-1.6-.94-2.04-1.71-.4-.71-.56-1.56-.81-2.3-.26-.75-.02-1.64-.2-2.41-.17-.77-.24-1.56-.39-2.34-.15-.78-.74-1.47-.93-2.24-.2-.8-.29-1.61-.54-2.36-.27-.78-.58-1.52-.92-2.24-.35-.74-.8-1.41-1.23-2.08-.43-.68-.61-1.59-1.13-2.2-.52-.6-1.46-.79-2.08-1.31-.6-.51-1.25-.91-1.94-1.34-.66-.4-1.3-.83-2.06-1.15-.71-.3-1.48-.37-2.28-.6-1.25-.36-1.45-1.14-1.53-1.66-.08-.51-.11-1.22.83-2.07.69-.63 1.61-.81 2.36-1.17.8-.38 1.62-.39 2.48-.52.85-.12 1.66-.54 2.55-.46.85.08 1.71.21 2.59.43.86.21 1.59.77 2.41 1.1.82.33 1.85.14 2.65.52.8.38 1.42 1.15 2.23 1.52.75.34 1.57.42 2.32.65.78.23 1.57.28 2.35.4.81.12 1.57.4 2.36.4.81 0 1.68.33 2.45.2.8-.14 1.59-.49 2.33-.75.75-.27 1.57-.54 2.26-.95.69-.41.92-1.47 1.52-2.01.6-.53 1.56-.69 2.06-1.34.51-.66 1.02-1.5.71-2.46-.19-.68-.77-.38-1.23-.3M74.11 60.82c.37-.58.56-1.29.95-1.86.39-.57.72-1.19 1.12-1.75.4-.56 1.33-.72 1.74-1.27.58-.77 1.01-1.86 2.15-2.49.6-.33 1.23-.34 1.79-.46.73-.16 1.36-.01 1.83-.02.82-.03 1.64-.44 2.47-.39.83.04 1.66.14 2.47.3.81.16 1.68.25 2.45.59.74.32 1.56.7 2.25 1.23.56.43.86 1.19 1.12 1.81.27.63.07 1.32 0 2.01-.07.67.15 1.49-.26 2.07-.61.87-1.65 1.6-2.61 1.74-.96.15-2.06-.39-2.9-1.04-.55-.42-1.36-.41-2.3-.5-1.91-.19-3.42.41-4.56 2.04-.54.77-1.07 1.55-1.58 2.34-.35.54-.64 1.1-1.15 1.39-.53.3-1.16.36-1.77.37-.76.01-1.73.14-2.41-.34-.58-.41-.84-1.24-1.13-1.84-.29-.62-.26-1.32-.22-2.01.06-.68.17-1.33.55-1.92M59.31 73c-1.07.04-1.78.16-2.32.53-.54.37-.92 1-1.31 2.02-.34.88-1.25 1.55-1.53 2.44-.25.8-.38 1.56-.98 2.03-.62.48-1.38.57-2.17.58-.42.01-.74-.2-1.16-.35-.66-.23-1.36-.27-1.79-.78-.44-.52-.75-1.17-.89-1.85-.13-.65-.26-1.42-.05-2.09.22-.7.38-1.44.62-2.13.25-.69.72-1.3.99-1.99.28-.68.85-1.23 1.15-1.89.21-.46.1-1.41.61-2.11.38-.52.86-1.18 1.49-1.62.59-.41 1.37-.42 1.94-.59.77-.23 1.45-.51 1.91-.55.69-.06 1.4-.12 2.1-.16.7-.04 1.4-.08 2.1-.09.7-.01 1.41.04 2.11.05 1.05.02 1.9.85 2.58 1.58.67.73 1.03 1.62 1.02 2.7-.01 1.08-.24 2.1-.93 2.8-.69.7-1.7 1.04-2.74 1.02-.93 0-1.84.42-2.75.45m40.12 7.46c-.19.78-.94 1.36-1.21 2.1-.28.75-.49 1.49-.85 2.2-.36.71-.46 1.56-.89 2.23-.43.67-1.15 1.1-1.65 1.72-.5.62-1.04 1.14-1.6 1.7s-1.01 1.2-1.62 1.7c-.61.5-1.27.9-1.92 1.33-.66.43-1.12 1.21-1.81 1.57-.7.36-1.51.5-2.24.78-.73.28-1.51.41-2.26.61-1.48.39-3.04.75-4.6.92-1.03.11-2.07.13-3.09.02-.86-.1-1.62-.88-2.45-1.03-.85-.15-1.75.03-2.58-.14-.72-.15-1.4-.48-2.1-.61-.73-.13-1.44-.41-2.14-.49-.74-.08-1.49.27-2.19.28-.74.02-1.44.09-2.13.26-1.02.26-2.16.19-2.99-.35-.82-.53-1.62-1.48-1.88-2.54-.17-.69.07-1.47.24-2.11.18-.66.76-1.06 1.23-1.54 1.96-1.98 3.63-1.76 6.26-1.69.8.02 1.62-.13 2.4-.04.8.1 1.6.21 2.37.35.8.15 1.59.28 2.35.44.7.14 1.37.33 2.04.45.7.13 1.33.64 2.01.73 2.74.34 4.26-.28 6.75-1.27.71-.28 1.52-.31 2.18-.71.66-.39 1.39-.7 1.99-1.19.6-.49 1.19-1.02 1.71-1.59.52-.58.61-1.48 1.04-2.13.43-.65 1.07-1.15 1.39-1.86.32-.71.8-1.39.99-2.15.42-1.69 1.55-2.97 3.2-3.56.72-.26 1.99-.32 2.73 0 2.09.9 1.76 3.85 1.32 5.61"/></svg>
<svg style="fill: rgb(62, 156, 205); width:80%; float:left; margin-top:3%;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1644 175.53">
<path d="M1639.81 87.56l-2.08.75 2.08-.75c-5.71-17.28-13.63-25.24-19.85-30.22-6.03-5.03-12.97-8.94-21.21-11.96-.6-.22-1.03-.76-1.1-1.41-.08-.65.2-1.28.73-1.64l15.27-10.47c2.26-1.55 3.65-4.14 3.72-6.94.08-2.8-1.18-5.47-3.35-7.15C1590.91 0 1568.69 0 1561.39 0c-26.6 0-40.38 9.43-46.23 15.06-4.91 4.7-7.3 7.92-8.82 11.88-.32.83-1.19 1.28-2.03 1.02-.83-.24-1.35-1.08-1.2-1.95l2.03-11.88c.43-2.52-.23-5.08-1.82-7.04-1.58-1.95-3.9-3.07-6.36-3.07h-37.92c-2.52 0-4.87 1.17-6.46 3.2-1.59 2.04-2.19 4.68-1.66 7.25 1.4 6.66 2.93 22.51-1.32 28.99-.92 1.41-1.95 2.1-3.55 2.38-.77.14-1.54.2-2.3.2-17.36 0-28.3-35.54-28.41-35.9-1.07-3.66-4.27-6.13-7.96-6.13h-27.08c-3.88 0-7.21 2.73-8.09 6.64l-27.99 123.13c-.2.89-1.03 1.47-1.9 1.31-.87-.14-1.49-.92-1.43-1.82l8.06-120.16c.16-2.37-.65-4.73-2.22-6.48-1.57-1.73-3.78-2.73-6.07-2.73h-70.88c-2.58 0-4.97 1.21-6.56 3.32-1.59 2.12-2.14 4.82-1.5 7.41l29.19 118.88c.22.89-.28 1.79-1.13 2.06-.84.28-1.78-.2-2.08-1.05l-44.86-125c-1.2-3.36-4.33-5.61-7.79-5.61h-19.1c-2.28 0-4.48.98-6.04 2.7-1.57 1.72-2.39 4.07-2.25 6.43 1.04 17.6-2.19 51.15-14.65 52.77-.59.08-1.19.11-1.77.11-17.46 0-34.43-34.33-41.01-55.98-1.09-3.61-4.28-6.04-7.93-6.04h-25.97c-4.2 0-7.74 3.25-8.25 7.57l-11.73 99.78c-.1.86-.82 1.51-1.67 1.52-.84 0-1.56-.64-1.67-1.5l-12.79-99.89c-.55-4.26-4.09-7.48-8.24-7.48h-25.85c-2.54 0-4.91 1.18-6.51 3.25l-28.45 36.99c-.51.67-1.41.85-2.13.45-.71-.39-1.05-1.25-.8-2.04l8.64-27.45c.82-2.62.38-5.51-1.18-7.74-1.56-2.22-4.07-3.54-6.72-3.54H868.69c-4.44 0-8.09 3.6-8.3 8.2l-1.22 26.43c-.04.88-.72 1.58-1.64 1.64-.8.09-1.56-.56-1.71-1.43l-4.71-27.72c-.7-4.12-4.14-7.12-8.19-7.12h-27.65c-3.2 0-6.17 2.65-7.76 6.93-.25.68-.94 1.14-1.65 1.11-.73-.03-1.35-.54-1.55-1.26-.24-.86-.48-1.57-.75-2.18-1.66-3.8-4.33-4.6-6.27-4.6h-48.21c-2.54 0-4.91 1.18-6.5 3.24-1.59 2.06-2.18 4.72-1.61 7.3 5.15 23.26 9.62 65.88-.33 81.2-1.94 2.99-4.24 4.63-7.24 5.14-15.29 2.61-28.19-20.54-36.33-40.43-9.92-24.26-14.98-49.37-15.03-49.63-.8-3.96-4.22-6.83-8.14-6.83h-16.08c-2.5 0-4.84 1.15-6.43 3.15-1.59 2.01-2.22 4.62-1.72 7.17l29.47 150.63c.78 4 4.21 6.9 8.15 6.9h63.9c3.64 0 6.82-2.41 7.92-6.01l41.09-134.3c.27-.87 1.16-1.37 2.01-1.16.86.22 1.41 1.08 1.26 1.97l-21.9 129.41c-.43 2.52.24 5.08 1.83 7.03 1.58 1.95 3.9 3.06 6.36 3.06h78.72c2.46 0 4.77-1.12 6.37-3.07.2-.25.37-.53.61-.95.67-1.15 2.45-1.04 2.97-.16l.24.42c1.53 2.36 4.1 3.77 6.87 3.77l92.59.07c3.01 0 5.79-1.7 7.27-4.44.06-.12 6.7-12.46 17.68-24.06 7.78-8.22 21.5-17.63 34.7-17.16 18.47.65 23.07 26.73 24.19 37.9.43 4.42 3.99 7.76 8.27 7.76h54.07c3.81 0 7.13-2.69 8.07-6.53.05-.21 5.23-20.63 16.87-22.27 8.22-1.31 18.06 15.6 21.26 23.49 1.3 3.23 4.31 5.32 7.68 5.32h29.94c2.28 0 4.49-.99 6.06-2.71 1.57-1.73 2.38-4.08 2.23-6.45-.62-9.85 1.19-31.78 10.53-32.76 8.93-.71 19.77 20.25 24.18 35.74 1.03 3.64 4.31 6.18 7.98 6.18h27.73c5.33 0 8.12-2.11 8.3-6.27.02-.61.02-1.24-.01-1.87-.04-.77.44-1.48 1.15-1.72.72-.24 1.53.04 1.94.69 1.41 2.21 2.07 4.19 2.6 5.78.34 1.02.6 1.77.89 2.27.43.72 1.17 1.11 1.95 1.08.2.02.48.04.84.04h26.02c3.7 0 4.14-1.58 5.31-5.8.23-.83.48-1.72.77-2.67.22-.72.87-1.2 1.61-1.2.74 0 1.38.49 1.6 1.21 1.8 5.96 4.66 8.73 8.99 8.73l26.67-.18c2.41 0 4.71-1.07 6.29-2.95 1.58-1.88 2.3-4.38 1.98-6.85-4.28-32.09-.13-61.95 8.87-63.91 8.95-1.92 25.49 30.16 34.61 67.21.94 3.82 4.25 6.48 8.06 6.48h35.89c4.04 0 7.48-2.99 8.18-7.11l3.99-23.35c.12-.68.62-1.22 1.28-1.38.66-.15 1.36.12 1.75.67 16.21 23.11 41.94 34.83 76.47 34.83 41.3 0 61.89-18.17 71.89-33.42 0 0 .16-.22.16-.23 10.21-15.71 11.8-33.47 4.92-54.27zm-760.76 64.68c-.25.65-.9 1.09-1.73 1.07-.74-.08-1.35-.65-1.49-1.4l-13.47-74.73c-.76-4.46.63-9.02 3.69-12.21 2.02-2.1 4.57-3.45 7.38-3.92 8.6-1.43 14.74-1.95 19.14-1.95 9.81 0 10.98 2.62 11.49 3.78 3.03 8.25-6.32 41.65-25.01 89.36zM995.27 64.8l-63.37 82.38c-.47.61-1.33.83-2.03.5-.7-.33-1.09-1.1-.95-1.88 4.2-23.1 12.89-63.96 23.96-78.07 4.53-5.76 14.6-7.38 23.97-7.38 7.13 0 13.86.94 17.41 1.7.52.11.97.46 1.19.94.29.6.22 1.29-.18 1.81zm62.58 18.69c-1.83 1.58-4.85 2.44-8.51 2.44h-.01c-5.79 0-12.39-2.12-17.67-5.68-6.62-4.46-9.33-9.67-9.64-12.77-.17-1.67.25-2.95 1.3-4.03 1.77-1.83 5.08-2.88 9.09-2.88 5.98 0 12.6 2.26 18.16 6.21 5.37 3.82 8.82 8.67 9 12.67.08 1.69-.47 2.97-1.72 4.04zm492.68-49.18c1.99-1.07 5.3-2.46 9.87-3.06 9.05-1.17 16.71 1.56 23.4 8.38.52.53.65 1.34.31 2.01-.33.65-.94 1.07-1.8.91-1.36-.25-1.81-.32-2.52-.42l-17.1-2.59c-3.64-.53-8.17-1.2-11.74-2.02-.69-.16-1.21-.74-1.3-1.46-.09-.72.26-1.42.88-1.75zm28.92 76.16c-.02.01-.04.01-.06.02l-.3.08c-1.61.47-5.22 1.27-11.4 1.27-22.82 0-37.53-8.2-44.97-25.06-.99-2.26-2.88-3.96-5.19-4.68-.78-.24-1.58-.36-2.37-.36-1.55 0-3.08.45-4.42 1.31l-16.33 10.6c-.57.37-1.29.36-1.86-.04-.55-.38-.82-1.06-.7-1.73l8.47-47.22c.15-.87.92-1.42 1.78-1.41.85.06 1.53.77 1.56 1.65.42 10.52 6.21 18.12 18.8 24.67 6.8 3.66 15.1 5.44 22.41 7.01l19.19 4.22c1.09.24 2.3.49 3.61.76 8.06 1.64 16.94 3.72 20.41 7.61 1.87 2.09 2.55 4.94 2.76 6.07 1.35 7.46-2.91 13.15-11.39 15.23zM593.04 3.78h-63.48c-4.79 0-9.62 1.65-11.73 5.6 0 0-8.39 15.63-19.79 36.86-.72 1.35-3.01.88-3-.61.01-4.57-1.12-9.3-3.45-14.53-1.86-4.17-14.59-27.32-58.28-27.32h-51.83c-3.89 0-7.42 1.08-8.59 4.2-1.32 5.52-2.63 11.04-3.94 16.56l-3.51 14.76c-.33 1.4-2.18 13.02-5.36 8.63-1.19-1.63-.37-17.41-.37-22.56V8.01c0-2.87-3.44-4.24-7.68-4.24H195.52c-2.57 0-5.02.85-6.75 2.35-1.74 1.5-2.59 3.5-2.36 5.51 1.06 9.16 1.17 23.14-8.05 23.14s-14.55-11.82-19.59-26.45c-1-2.9-4.74-4.54-8.5-4.54H10.6C5.22 3.78.52 7.17.58 10.55L0 167.43c.04 2.43 3.16 4.49 7.26 4.49h163.17c4.83 0 8.83-3.11 9.12-6.91.9-11.61 7.96-25.05 16.86-25.05 9.7 0 19.12 14.49 23.14 26.53 1.05 3.15 4.68 5.44 8.81 5.44h96.1c2.18 0 4.26-.93 5.72-2.03 1.45-1.1 2.15-2.57 1.92-4.04l-14.96-93.03c-.11-.73.24-1.47.96-2.02.73-.55 1.77-.86 2.86-.86h18.2c4.59 0 11.23-.42 15.21 1.95 3.17 1.88 1.8 6.44 1.14 9.21-2.49 10.49-13.31 67.01-17.54 84.79-.08.36-.16.71-.25 1.07-.93 2.55 1.94 4.98 5.83 4.98h36.73c2.05 0 4.04-.65 5.33-1.74 1.29-1.09 1.73-2.5 1.16-3.77-3.83-8.49-9.59-17.9-9.58-27.5.01-8.56 7.58-11.88 14.73-7.67 11.76 6.92 18.95 24 20.72 36.84.3 2.15 3.11 3.83 6.41 3.83 0 0 53.48.02 60.86.03 3.54.01 6.83-1.57 8.68-4.21 2.93-4.16 7.49-10.24 10.61-12.64 9.26-7.11 21.32-8.66 32.3-5.78 4.13 1.09 8.12 2.99 11.58 5.61 3.69 2.79 5.15 5.85 7.49 9.73 3.57 5.92 5.64 7.13 11.3 7.26 2.3.05 26.26 0 30.89 0 7.35 0 7.35-6.37 7.35-6.37V8.23c-.04-3.38-2.81-4.45-7.07-4.45zM137.71 112.12c-2.42 6.68-5.26 13.24-8.38 19.69-1.78 3.68-3.49 9.05-7.77 11.14-1.04.51-2.22.82-3.6.87-19.65.45-52.51-2.12-50.68-13.43 1.36-8.41 10.28-13.17 44.13-14.97 4.29-.23 7.53-2.35 7.53-4.94l-4.07-17.2c0-2.67-3.62-4.89-8.07-4.96-18.17-.27-51.67-3.95-51.62-13.64.06-11.51 30.98-15.23 45.44-15.63 4.43-.13 7.9-2.3 7.9-4.96l-4.07-20.24c0-2 3.23-2.84 4.73-1.23 15 16.11 30.2 39.77 33.6 51.23 2.61 8.81-2.07 19.99-5.07 28.27zm127.51 28.35c-.38 2.3-4.12 3.08-5.85 1.21-23.12-25.09-39.47-55.58-41.7-65.68-2.16-9.79-.67-29.63 6.69-46.11 1.77-3.96 8.1-2.86 8.1 1.42v33.4c0 2.87 3.56 5.21 7.94 5.21h32.12c1.12 0 2.2.32 2.95.86.75.55 1.11 1.29 1 2.02l-11.25 67.67zm148.9-68.34c-3.09.47-5.86.48-8.2.05-1.37-.25-2.6-.66-3.66-1.22-2.25-1.17-3.67-2.98-4.09-5.22-1.14-6 4.97-13.22 15.8-18.39 8.34-3.97 17.26-5.26 22.68-3.35 2.96 1.05 4.93 3.03 5.54 5.55.46 1.93.36 5.06-2.75 9.02-5.06 6.46-15.69 12.11-25.32 13.56zm67.28 4.25c-6.27 11.98-18.68 35.65-25.58 48.5-1.42 2.63-5.7 2.64-7.15.03-1.49-2.69-10.98-17.07-11.57-21.14-1.29-9.05 14.94-13.07 21.92-16.14 7.85-3.45 15-8.74 19.84-12.79 1.27-1.07 3.26.16 2.54 1.54zm71.46 41.54c-1.34 1.86-3.61 3.12-6.54 3.63-.68.12-1.38.2-2.12.24-6.01.33-13.89-1.93-20.75-6.06-10.2-6.13-15-13.95-11.96-19.45 2.45-4.44 9.12-5.77 17.87-3.53 10.59 2.71 20.88 10.04 23.94 17.05 1.68 3.88.69 6.56-.44 8.12z"/></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is an html document. Use one svg element per document.svg.

Comment: Oh that worked thank you! I didn't realize you could put SVG tags just on their own  First time using SVG :)

Comment: @enxaneta: If your solution worked, post it as an answer.